# Cannot get rid of isearch overlays

Tags: hooks, isearch, overlays

The following code

```lisp
(defun nordlow/isearch-previous-symbol-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (cond ((eq last-command 'nordlow/isearch-previous-symbol-at-point)
         (isearch-repeat-backward))    ;avoid flickering
        ((eq last-command 'nordlow/isearch-next-symbol-at-point)
         (isearch-repeat-backward 1))  ;avoid flickering
        (t
         (let (case-fold-search)
           (isearch-forward-symbol-at-point -1)))))
(defun nordlow/isearch-next-symbol-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (cond ((eq last-command 'nordlow/isearch-next-symbol-at-point)
         (isearch-repeat-forward))     ;avoid flickering
        ((eq last-command 'nordlow/isearch-previous-symbol-at-point)
         (isearch-repeat-forward 1))   ;avoid flickering
        (t
         (let (case-fold-search)
           (isearch-forward-symbol-at-point +1)))))
```

reuses `isearch` to provide navigation of all instances of the current symbol at point similar to what the packages https://github.com/nschum/highlight-symbol.el and https://github.com/elp-revive/auto-highlight-symbol does.

It works except that the font overlays are not removed when another command is called after either `nordlow/isearch-previous-symbol-at-point` or `nordlow/isearch-next-symbol-at-point` is called. How can I make these overlays be removed in this case?

One solution is to write a new hook similar to `isearch-post-command-hook` and add it to `pre-command-hook`s.

I would, btw, be very happy to have these two function be integrated into `isearch.el`.

Comment: As you found a solution, please write an Answer to your question -- you can then Accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution

```lisp
(defun nordlow/isearch-navigate-symbol-pre-command-hook ()
  (when (memq last-command '(nordlow/isearch-previous-symbol-at-point
                             nordlow/isearch-next-symbol-at-point))
    (isearch-done)
    (isearch-clean-overlays)))
(add-hook 'pre-command-hook 'nordlow/isearch-navigate-symbol-pre-command-hook)
```